Which Foreground Service type is suitable for Updating Software of Connected Bluetooth Device in Android?
I want to update connected bluetooth device software from foreground service which service type is good "dataSync" or "connectedDevice" sevice?  Update may take 15 to 20 minutes.
android:foregroundServiceType="connectedDevice"


There is official android document for this : Click Here
For updating the software of a connected Bluetooth device in Android, the most suitable type of Foreground Service would be one with the ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_CONNECTED_DEVICE flag. This type is specifically designed for services interacting with connected devices like Bluetooth peripherals.
Software updates can take time, and a foreground service ensures the update process continues even if the app is moved to the background.
Example :
<service
android:name=".YourUpdateService"
android:foregroundServiceType="connectedDevice" />


startForegroundService(new Intent(this, YourUpdateService.class));
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification, 
ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_CONNECTED_DEVICE);

This will ensure your Bluetooth device update process is stable and user-friendly.

Thanks for your answer it is helpful.  One more thing in the above code  I am getting a warning:
Field requires API level 29 (current min is 24): android.content.pm.ServiceInfo#FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_CONNECTED_DEVICE

ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_CONNECTED_DEVICE was introduced in API level 29 (Android 10),
you can modify your code to avoid the warning and still leverage the newer

Looking into the Foreground service types documentation connectedDevice seems to be the more appropriate choice for your use case:
connectedDevice is specifically designed for tasks that involve managing the connection to external devices. Since you're updating the software of a bluetooth device, this is the better fit for you. It ensures that the system treats your service as critical for maintaining the device connection and functioning while the task runs.
dataSync is used for services that handle syncing data between devices. While updating firmware involves data transfer, the focus in your case should be on managing the connection to the Bluetooth device.

Thank you very much for your answer. Also this new service type connectedDevice is added in android 10. Will it work in older version  of android?

On devices prior to android 10 the foreground service will simply run as regular foreground service without any extra optimizations for managing device connections.

Usually you will do something like this to handle different android versions:
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
// start foreground service with connected device type.
} else {
// start foreground service without specific type.
}
